# Xcode Swift - Adding data in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I'm trying to add 'Default' data in Core Data. I know there are some duplicate's for this question, but none have really took my understanding and had a good answer.

I have the following data that i would like to add:

```
Description: Set 1
URI: spotify:track:1puJlKuYGH58SAFgXREUpE
Time Stamp: 0:49:00 (49 seconds)
Duration: 30 seconds
Crossfade: 10 seconds
File: 1.25s Next Up.mp3
```

So far I have checked if any data exists in the Core Data, if it doesn't then add the 'Default'.

```
var appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Music", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    let request = NSFetchRequest()
    request.entity = entity
    request.fetchLimit = 1
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Music")
    let error: NSErrorPointer? = nil

    let results: NSArray? = managedObjectContext!.executeRequest(request)
    if let res = results{
        if res.count == 0
        {
            //TODO: Add the default musicSet's here
            return true
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
        return true
    }
}
```

I have also got the properties:

```
@NSManaged var voiceover: String?
@NSManaged var xfade: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var duration: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var starttime: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var uri: String?
```

I know that after the res.count == 0, I can add my data, but how to do this i'm not 100% sure? i tried doing

```
.setValue("spotify:track:1puJlKuYGH58SAFgXREUpE", forkey: "uri")
```

I'm again not sure if this is the correct way in doing this? I'm fairly new to all this! so i apologies ! But any help would be great! please

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I don't think you need to set a predicate for your fetch first as you want to return any `Music` objects you may already have.)

Create a new `NSManagedObject` and add it to your `NSManagedObjectContext` :

```
let defaultMusic=NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Music",
  inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!) as! Music
```

Set its properties with:

```
defaultMusic.xfade=10.0
defaultMusic.duration=30.0
```

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add few data, you can use the `NSUserDefaults` in this way to put some info:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(self.user_name, forKey: "user_name")
```

In this way you can retrieve those info in another `Controller`:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
user_name = defaults.stringForKey("user_name")
```

Otherwise if you want to save many informations you can use the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/).